# Exception thrown inside a synchronized block java/android

Tags: java, android

I'm experiencing something weird when it comes to synchronized blocks. I have a cache that needs to be inside a synchronized block. There is an exception happening inside the block and for some reason is not going to the catch block. I tried debugging it, and I saw that it calls InvocationTargetException constructor and then it goes to ThreadGroup uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) method.

I have a try catch surrounding the synchronized block, in fact there is another inner try-catch covering the line of code where the exception happens...

Does anyone know why it's not getting it to the catch block?

I even try to literally try to catch the InvocationTargetException as well as the Exception, and as expected, it doesn't compile because nothing inside is throwing that kind of exception. I do understand the reason of the exception though, my concern is that it was't caught and kill the thread.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 
{
    if(lastKnownLatitude != null && lastKnownLongitude != null)
    {
            try
            {

                synchronized (dataManager.getRegisteredGeo()) {for(String geoName : dataManager.getRegisteredGeo().keySet())
                    {
                        GeoNotification geoNotification = dataManager.getRegisteredGeo().get(geoName);
                        boolean isInside = geoNotification.isLocationInsideFence(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());


                        geoNotification.setLastKnownDeviceInside(isInside);
                        GeoUpdateMsg updateMsg = new GeoUpdateMsg(geoNotification.getTransactionId());
                        updateMsg.sendData(updateMsg.serializeObjectIntoXml());

                    }   
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Logger.LogError("Exception while processing  geo notifications" + e.getMessage());
            }
    }
}
```

This is the event that fires when the device location changed

This is what I got from the log cat, the exception wasn't caught

```
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/convert/FromString
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:267)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.MethodDetail.<init>(MethodDetail.java:57)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.DetailScanner.methods(DetailScanner.java:411)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.DetailScanner.scan(DetailScanner.java:366)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.DetailScanner.<init>(DetailScanner.java:140)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.DetailExtractor.getDetail(DetailExtractor.java:107)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Support.getDetail(Support.java:278)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Support.getDetail(Support.java:271)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.ScannerFactory.getInstance(ScannerFactory.java:76)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Support.getScanner(Support.java:357)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getScanner(Source.java:271)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Source.getCaller(Source.java:300)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.writeReplace(Composite.java:1147)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.writeUnion(Composite.java:1124)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.writeElements(Composite.java:1098)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.writeSection(Composite.java:1004)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.write(Composite.java:975)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.write(Composite.java:952)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.write(Traverser.java:236)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.write(Traverser.java:208)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.write(Traverser.java:186)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1180)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1162)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1140)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1259)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1241)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.write(Persister.java:1222)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at com.medusa.client.transactions.TransactionsGoingOut.serializeObjectIntoXml(TransactionsGoingOut.java:57)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at com.medusa.client.transactions.messages.GeoFenceUpdateMsg.serializeObjectIntoXml(GeoFenceUpdateMsg.java:64)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at com.medusa.client.smsIntercept.GPSTracker.onLocationChanged(GPSTracker.java:312)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:255)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:184)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:200)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.joda.convert.FromString" on path: /data/app/com.nomotion.smsIntercept-1.apk
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-22 13:12:35.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2121):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
```

Comment: post your code here !!

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of the error?

Comment: I suspect that the `Exception` is not being thrown within the `try` sentence you're showing, but a stack trace would clarify that.

Comment: it's just this class isn't recognized `org.joda.convert.FromString` make sure you're properly integrating your libraries or you don't reference the same library multiple times

Comment: Yeah. I mean I understood the problem, but it should've been caught...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the exception isn't caught because it's an `Error` and not an `Exception`.

For debugging purposes **only**: try to change your "catch Exception" to a "catch Throwable", you will get more information about your problem.

For possible solutions: see comments to your post.